# Double Trapezoidal Integral in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a two-dimensional function $f(x,y)=\exp(y-x)$. I would like to compute the double integral $\int_{0}^{10}\int_{0}^{10}f(x,y) dx dy$ using NumPy trapz. After some reading, they say I should just repeat the trapz twice but it's not working. I have tried the following

```
import numpy as np

def distFunc(x,y):
    f = np.exp(-x+y)
    return f

# Values in x to evaluate the integral.
x = np.linspace(.1, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(.1, 10, 100)

list1=distFunc(x,y)
int_exp2d = np.trapz(np.trapz(list1, y, axis=0), x, axis=0)
```

The code always gives the error

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I don't know how to fix this so that the code can work. I thought the inner trapz was to integrate along y first then we end by the second along x. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert `x` and `y` to 2D arrays which can be done conveniently in numpy with `np.meshgrid`.  This way, when you call `distfunc` it will return a 2D array which can be integrated along one axis first and then the other.  As your code stands right now, you are passing a 1D list to the first integral (which is fine) and then the second integral receives a scalar value.

```
import numpy as np

def distFunc(x,y):
    f = np.exp(-x+y)
    return f

# Values in x to evaluate the integral.
x = np.linspace(.1, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(.1, 10, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

list1=distFunc(X, Y)
int_exp2d = np.trapz(np.trapz(list1, y, axis=0), x, axis=0)
```

Comment: Just an addition: If he wants to integrate from x,y=0 to x,y=10 it should be `np.linspace(0.0, 10, 100)` for x and y.