# 2D Integration over a flattened Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integration

I'm hoping to find a way around the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893049/double-trapezoidal-integral-in-numpy) to use 2D arrays in order to do 2D numerical integration.

```
import numpy as np
ksize = 50
a        = 1.0
kdom     = np.pi / a 
x = np.linspace(- kdom, kdom, ksize)  
y = np.linspace(- kdom, kdom, ksize)    
dk = x[1]-x[0]
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
eigval = np.cos(X)+np.cos(Y)
eigvalflat = eigval.flatten()
intval = np.trapz(np.trapz(eigval,x),y)

sumval = np.sum(eigvalflat)*dk/ksize

print(intval,sumval)
```

Given my dummy example above, I'd like to find a way to properly integrate the 1D array (`eigvalflat`) while still as a flattened array even though it is a double integral.

Answer (score 0):

Computationally, if the integrand is not separable, then the answer is that you can't recast the double integral as a single integral, unless you compute the integral one dimension at a time, which is what the assignment to `intval` is essentially doing.

Analytically, you'll have a better chance by asking yourself the question: given the 2d region of the integral (a rectangle in your example), can one find an integral over the *boundary* of that region? For that, [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) has you covered with necessary and sufficient conditions.